# User-defined exception: <unprintable ... object>

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7

I tried to define my own exception class in python 2.7, deriving from `BaseException`.

```
class NestedCommentException(BaseException):
    """
    Exception for nested comments
    """
    def __init__(self, file_path, list_lines):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.list_lines = list_lines

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'File {0} contains nested comments at lines {1}'.format(self.file_path, ', '.join(self.list_lines))
```

But when throwing it, it cannot be printed: `raise NestedCommentException(file_path, list_lines)` triggers

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DATA\FP12210\My Documents\Outils\SVN\05_impl\2_tools\svn_tag_setup.py", line 85, in <module>
    tag_checks()
  File "D:\DATA\FP12210\My Documents\Outils\SVN\05_impl\2_tools\svn_tag_setup.py", line 66, in tag_checks
    check_nested_comments(ddl_path)
  File "D:\DATA\FP12210\My Documents\Outils\SVN\05_impl\2_tools\svn_tag_setup.py", line 54, in check_nested_comments
    raise NestedCommentException(file_path, list_lines)
NestedCommentException: <unprintable NestedCommentException object>
```

Can you please explain why this happens, even if I defined `__str__` and `__repr__` methods ?

Comment: Is there a reason you're inheriting from `BaseException` rather than just `Exception`?

Comment: Well, I first created this class deriving from `object`, and I had: `TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NestedCommentException`. I tried to make it derive from `Exception`, same behaviour.

Comment: `Exception` is derived from `BaseException` and is what you should use for user defined exceptions.

Comment: Perhaps the variables self.file_path or self.list_lines are messing it up somehow. Try removing them from the __str__ method and see what happens.

Comment: simple test with raise works, so what different you are doing? can you see how you raise it with what variables?

Comment: Are there non-ASCII characters in the strings in list_lines, by any chance?

Comment: *mgilson*: ok for next time ! *Lanaru*: you're right, I was trying to join integers, not string, this is why... Many thanks, it now works I have a list of strings. Please post this comment in order for me to accept it. *Zero Piraeus*: I checked, no strange characters, but good idea anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that you have unicode in `file_path` or `list_lines` variables dues to which it is not being printed on a console without unicode capabilities.

or any other exception in `__str__` can cause such strange behavior, best way is to catch exception and see whats is happening, use debugger too

```
def __str__(self):
    try:
        s =  'File {0} contains nested comments at lines {1}'.format(self.file_path, ', '.join(self.list_lines))
    except Exception,e:
        print "-----",type(e),e
    return s
```

Comment: Problem resided indeed in `__str__` (in `', '.join(self.list_lines)`, to be precise). Thanks !

Answer (score 13):

### TL;DR

When you see this thing, it basically means that some kind of exception has been raised in `__str__()` of your object.  So unless the problem is trivial enough to see at the first sight (e.g. forgotten "%s"), either

- wrap the `__str__` body in a try/except clause as Anurag advices, or
- instantiate your exception and call the `__str__` (or any methods you may have
  overridden) manually, outside the traceback module, so that you get the full
  description of the exception.

### Analysis

Actually this `<unprintable MyException object>` can come from various functions in traceback module, which, when trying to get a string (i.e. "printable") version of a value (exception), it

1. calls `str()` on it, and if anything goes wrong,
2. tries to treat it as unicode and convert it to ASCII, and if still anything
   goes wrong
3. simply prints the above representation.

Responsible code (same in 2.6 and 2.7):

> ```
> def _some_str(value):
>     try:
>         return str(value)
>     except Exception:
>         pass
>     try:
>         value = unicode(value)
>         return value.encode("ascii", "backslashreplace")
>     except Exception:
>         pass
>     return '<unprintable %s object>' % type(value).__name__
> ```

As you can see, *any* exceptions coming from the `str()` call or the `unicode.encode()` call are ceased in the process and only the "cryptic" representation is given.

### Note on traceback module vs. Python interpreter

Contrary to what [`traceback` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) tells us:

> It exactly mimics the behavior of the Python interpreter when it prints
>   a stack trace.

the representation given by Python interpreter is slightly different here.  As opposed to the "unprintable" message, the interpreter would simply display the name of the exception, ceasing any actual exceptions as well.

Here is [a simple script](https://gist.github.com/AloisMahdal/6670606) that demonstrates all three approaches:  leaving the exception to Python interpreter, using traceback module, or calling the function by hand.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, traceback

class Boom(Exception):

    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        self.foo, self.bar, self.baz = foo, bar, baz

    def __str__(self):
        return ("boom! foo: %s, bar: %s, baz: "     # ouch! forgot an %s!
                % (self.foo, self.bar, self.baz))

def goBoom(): raise Boom(foo='FOO', bar='BAR', baz='BAZ')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if sys.argv[1].startswith("i"):
        goBoom()
        # __main__.Boom

    elif sys.argv[1].startswith("t"):
        try:    goBoom()
        except: traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        # Boom: <unprintable Boom object>

    elif sys.argv[1].startswith("m"):
        e = Boom(foo='FOO', bar='BAR', baz='BAZ')
        e.__str__()
        # TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

    else: pass
```