# How to save a record to an alternate model?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

My project is in flask-admin using flask-sqlalchemy as the ORM.

Here's my model class:

```
class history_records(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
  table = db.Column(db.String(80))
  field_name = db.Column(db.String(80))
  old_value = db.Column(db.String(80))
  new_value = db.Column(db.Text)
  updated_datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime,default=datetime.utcnow())
  updated_by = db.Column(db.String(80),db.ForeignKey('users.username'))

  def __init__(self,table="",field_name="",updated_datetime=""):
    self.name = table + ' - ' + field_name + ' - ' + updated_datetime

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

Then:

```
class my_view(ModelView):
  #... form configs ...

  def on_model_change(self,form,model,is_created=False):
    #...do some stuff...
    history = history_records() # .get_create_form()

    history.table = model_name
    history.field_name = field_name
    history.old_value = old_value
    history.new_value = new_value
```

All my other views inherit from `my_view` and I am specifically trying to write it so I don't have to have a custom `on_model_change` in each view using the field names for that view.

The piece I am missing is how to get my application to save the `history_records` record that the `on_model_change` method creates to the database (postgres). An instance of the class is instantiated and it has the requisite information, **so how do I save the instance to the database?**

I have been referencing these pages without success:

- [Flask-Admin: How to change model using on_model_change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127156/flask-admin-how-to-change-model-using-on-model-change)
- [Make primary-key fields editable in Flask-Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207704/make-primary-key-fields-editable-in-flask-admin) (`peewee` specific)
- [Unable to create models on Flask-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254840/unable-to-create-models-on-flask-admin) (suggests setting default values for variables passed to **init** model method, which I've done)
- [Customize (override) Flask-Admin's Submit method from edit view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140030/customize-override-flask-admins-submit-method-from-edit-view/21798302#21798302) (@makaron's answer is insightful)
- [Flask-admin; To add custom logic during row insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708006/flask-admin-to-add-custom-logic-during-row-insertion)
- [how to use flask-admin for editing modelview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970076/how-to-use-flask-admin-for-editing-modelview)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save the history instance you need to add it to the view's session e.g.

```
def on_model_change(self,form,model,is_created=False):
    #...do some stuff...
    history = history_records() # .get_create_form()

    history.table = model_name
    history.field_name = field_name
    history.old_value = old_value
    history.new_value = new_value
    self.session.add(history)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @pjcunningham. I added the line `self.session.add(history)` but that resulted in getting this error: ProgrammingError: <unprintable ProgrammingError object>

Comment: Based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13089951/1807668 I cast the variables `model_name`, `field_name`, `old_value`, and `new_value` to `str()` and then it worked.